# Differentiating an exponential function

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to calculate a Christoffel symbol, but I'm stuck on showing that $$\frac{\partial(e^{2A})}{\partial r}=2e^{2A}\frac{\partial A}{\partial r}\ 
 ? $$

Nice easy steps would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is the problem? This is the chain rule. Assumming $A = A(r)$, $A$ is differentiable w.r. to $r$ and $e^x$ is the common exponential function.

Comment: Thomas, a bit simpler please. What form of chain rule? I know $\frac{d\left(e^{x}\right)}{dx}=e^{x}$
  but how do I calculate $\frac{\partial\left(e^{2A}\right)}{\partial r}$
 . Yes, $A$
  is a function of $r$
 . Afraid I've never heard of “common exponential function”.

Comment: It's just the ordinary chain rule. Would you know how to differentiate $e^{2r^5}$, for example?

Comment: Hans Lundmark - I'd let $u=2r^{5}$,
 $\frac{du}{dr}=10r^{4},y=e^{u}$
 $\frac{dy}{du}=ue^{u}$
  (I think), therefore $\frac{dy}{dr}=\frac{du}{dr}\frac{dy}{du}$
 . Is that OK? I think I'm confused about $A$
  not being an explicit function of $r$
 . Thanks.

Comment: @Peter4075: Good! Then you've got it! Just take $u=2A$ in your case. You will have $du/dr=2 dA/dr$, and that's all there is to it.

Comment: Hans Lundmark: $u=A$
  gives $\frac{du}{dr}=2\frac{dA}{dr}$
  (though I'd normally want to differentiate wrt A, but I'll take your word that's OK), then $\frac{d\left(e^{2A}\right)}{du}=\frac{d\left(e^{u}\right)}{du}=e^{u}$
  so $\frac{d\left(e^{2A}\right)}{dr}=\frac{du}{dr}\frac{d\left(e^{2A}\right)}{du}=2e^{2A}\frac{dA}{dr}$
 . I would never have got that. Thank you.

Comment: Dumb question: Is this a matrix exponential? Is that why you're worried? Best,

Comment: Dylan Moreland: I'm just not very good at calculus!

Comment: Another dumb question then: how come you're calculating Christoffel symbols...? No offence, but that sounds quite advanced if you're having trouble with the chain rule. (P.S. For messages to another user, put "@" before the user name, and they will get notification in their inbox at the upper left of the page.)

Comment: And by the way: perhaps if you write $u=A(r)$ it's easier to see why $r$ is the variable to differentiate with respect to; $A(r)$ just symbolizes any function of $r$, like $A(r)=r^5$ in the example.

Comment: Hans Lundmark: Thanks for that. In my own, mathematically inept, way I'm attempting to understand the basics of general relativity. I'm now trying to work through a simple derivation of the Schwarzschild metric. I concur with Einstein when he said, "Do not worry about your difficulties in mathematics. I can assure you mine are still greater." But not as great as mine are!

Comment: @HansLundmark - I forgot the @. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your're welcome, Peter. Good luck with the general relativity! (It's not easy!)

Answer (score 1):

When $A$ is a scalar function of $r$, the formula $\frac{d }{d r}e^{2A}=2e^{2A}\frac{dA}{dr}$ is nothing but the chain rule.

When $A$ is a matrix, one has to watch out for the lack of commutativity. If $A$ and $\frac{dA}{dr}$ commute, everything works as for scalars. Otherwise, the formula breaks down: for example, if 
$$A(r)=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ r & 0\end{pmatrix} \tag1$$
then 
$$\frac{d}{dr}_{\, \big|r=0} \exp A(r) = \begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 1/6 \\ 1 & 1/2\end{pmatrix}\tag2$$
which is not a product of $A'(0)=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\exp A(0)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, in either order: 
$$A'(0)\exp A(0) =\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\qquad  (\exp A(0)) \,A'(0)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\tag3$$
One may observe in passing that the average of two products in (3) is
$$\frac12 (A'(0)\exp A(0) + (\exp A(0)) \,A'(0)) = \begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 0 \\ 1 & 1/2\end{pmatrix} \tag4$$
which does a decent job of approximating (2). This suggests that (4) may be the beginning of a power series that gives the correct value of the derivative of matrix exponential, which (I guess) can be fished out of the [Zassenhaus formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula).